# How to have sequence in a function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, sequence

Below is a code, which works fine without function/function handles. However, I have to write a function so that I can use optimization function of "lsqcurvefit" in MATLAB and optimize parameters constant(1) and constant(2).

```
L=zeros(n,length(S)); % Height of elements
L(:,1)=Linitial; % Height of elements for day zero
for jj=1:length(S)
   if jj==1
       continue
   end
    for j=1:n % n is 101 (previously defined...)
    
     L(j,jj) = @(constant, i_dt) L(j,jj-1) - (i_dt(j,jj).*constant(1).*((L(j,jj-1)./hs)-1)^constant(2)); %*****
     
    end
end

height_pred = @(constant,i_dt) sum(L); %heigh_pred(1) is known and previously defined
options = optimoptions('lsqcurvefit','FinDiffType','central',...
    'TolFun',1e-10);
constant = lsqcurvefit(height_pred,constant0,i_dt,height_meas,lb,ub,options);
```

When I run above code, I receive the error "Conversion to double from function_handle is not possible" for line with 5 stars (*****).

If I remove function handle and instead write a function at the end of my code like below:

```
L=zeros(n,length(S)); % Height of elements
L(:,1)=Linitial; % Height of elements for day zero
for jj=1:length(S)

      for j=1:n % n is 101 (previously defined...)
         L(j,jj) = Nelfun(j,jj);
      end
end

height_pred = @(constant,i_dt) sum(L); %heigh_pred(1) is known and previously defined
options = optimoptions('lsqcurvefit','FinDiffType','central',...
    'TolFun',1e-10);
constant = lsqcurvefit(height_pred,constant0,i_dt,height_meas,lb,ub,options);

function L = Nelfun(constant,i_dt)
for jj=1:145
   if jj==1
       L(:,1)=0.0187600000000000;
       continue
   end
      for j=1:101
         L(j,jj-1);
         L(j,jj) = L(j,jj-1) - (i_dt(j,jj).*constant(1).*((L(j,jj-1)./hs)-1)^constant(2)); %*****
      end
end
end
```

I receive the error

```
"Index exceeds matrix dimensions" for line with (*****).
```

Size of matrix i_dt is (101,145), L is (101,145), height_meas(1,145), and height_pred(1,145).

L(j,jj) for jj==1 is known but then should be calculated and optimized for L(:,2) to L(:,145).

```
              ***
```

Thanks to Praveen, "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" issue is resolved, but now I receive the error

```
"Error using snls (line 183)
Finite difference Jacobian at initial point contains Inf or NaN values. lsqcurvefit cannot continue."
```

for below code:

```
lb = [0.000000000001,0.05]; ub = [1,50]; constant0 = [1.06e-09,15.2];

height_pred = @(constant,i_dt) sum(Nelfun(constant,i_dt)); 

options = optimoptions('lsqcurvefit','FinDiffType','central',...
    'TolFun',1e-10);
constant = lsqcurvefit(height_pred,constant0,i_dt,height_meas,lb,ub,options);

function L = Nelfun(constant,i_dt)
L=zeros(size(i_dt));
n=101; % number of nodes
ei=2.05613504572765; 
e0=ei.*ones(n,1);
Hsolid=0.613847219422639; 
hs = Hsolid./(n-1);
for JJ=1:size(i_dt,2)
   if JJ==1
     for j=1:n
         Linitial0=hs.*(1+e0);
         Linitial0(1)=0;
     end
     L(:,JJ) = Linitial0;
     continue
   end
     for J=1:size(i_dt,1)
         L(J,JJ) = L(J,JJ-1) - (i_dt(J,JJ).*constant(1).*((L(J,JJ-1)./hs)-1)^constant(2));
     end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, you can't make an array of function handles. you can use cell arrays but I can't understand why you need it.

Let's work your second case.

```
%I don't know what is hs, I assume it a scalar
hs=myhs;
%call the Nelfun in your function handle
height_pred = @(constant,i_dt) Nelfun(constant,i_dt,hs);


options = optimoptions('lsqcurvefit','FinDiffType','central',...
    'TolFun',1e-10);
% Constant0 should be 2 element array
constant0=[0,0];
constant = lsqcurvefit(height_pred,constant0,i_dt,height_meas,lb,ub,options);

function L = Nelfun(constant,i_dt,hs)% why hs is not passed
L=zeros(size(i_dt)); % Always initialize before filling it up
for jj=1:size(i_dt,2) %use adaptive indexing
   if jj==1
       L(:,jj)=0.0187600000000000;
       continue
   end
      for j=1:size(i_dt,1) %use adaptive indexing
         L(j,jj) = L(j,jj-1) - (i_dt(j,jj).*constant(1).*((L(j,jj-1)./hs)-1)^constant(2));
      end
   
end
```

Comment: I'm so grateful to your help! I do not receive error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" anymore. I made your suggested corrections and as you said I forgot to copy some of the lines from my original code to my question above. I however, receive new errors for lsqcurvefit function :"Finite difference Jacobian at initial point contains Inf or NaN values. lsqcurvefit cannot continue.". I need to give you my updated code, but since I am not allowed to answer my own question based on stackoverflow policies, I will edit my above question and add the new code.

Comment: I believe the new errors come from the options I have set in my lsqcurvefit function. I need to learn how to apply options such that my results are global minimum and not local minimum, while those options are not causing errors. Thank you again for your valuable answer.

Comment: It looks like the default gradient calculation broke because of your problem definition. I'm not a expert in optimization. I can't help you much here. Give non-linear least squares without or manual jacobian calculation like [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/nonlinear-least-squares-with-full-jacobian.html) a try.  I would also make surface plot of MSE of the entire parameter space and tune input parameters. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you very much Praveen! Very interesting! I however was able to stop the new errors by switching from "central" to the default "forward" method in "finite difference type" option. I'll try what you said to improve the code.